# Subset different vector elements within a list

Tags: r, list, vector, subset

Assume I have this list of vectors:

```
mylist <- list(a=1:3,b=4:1,c=1:5)
mylist
$a
[1] 1 2 3
$b
[1] 4 3 2 1
$c
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to get the last or the max element of each vector like this for the last element:

```
$a
[1] 3
$b
[1] 1
$c
[1] 5
```

What I have tried so far:

First use `lapply` and the `length` function to get the last element index and then subset:

```
last <- unlist(lapply(mylist, length))
lapply(mylist,"[", last) # not working
```

Then I tried to use `sapply` with `lapply`. This is working, but I'm not sure whether this is generally valid. There must be a better base R solution (without loops!).

```
mymatrix <- sapply(last, function(x) lapply(mylist, "[",x))
diag(mymatrix)
$a
[1] 3
$b
[1] 1
$c
[1] 5
```

Comment: For the `max` isn't this just `lapply(mylist, max)`?

Comment: Yes this is true. I actually need not the max. Only different indeces per vector.

Comment: How are the indices defined then? For the last element you can use `lapply(mylist, tail, 1)`

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(mylist, which.max)`?

Comment: another approach (with R 3.2 version at minimum): `unlist(mylist)[cumsum(lengths(mylist))]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your solutions. Let assume that the indeces are for example `c(1,2,3)`. This is an artificial one, but could happen. My question is whether there is a way to subset vectors within a list when you only have the indeses `c(1,2,3)` and you're not allowed to use a `for` loop.?

Comment: ```mapply(`[`, mylist, 1:3)```?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Making this a CV as there were many contributes here and worth summing this up)

If you have some function you want to apply on your list, a simple `lapply` should do, such as

```
lapply(mylist, max) # retrieving the maximum values
```

Or

```
lapply(mylist, tail, 1) # retrieving the last values (by @docendo)
```

---

If you want to operate on two vectors simultaneously, you could use `mapply` or `Map`

```
Map(`[`, mylist, lengths(mylist)) # A Map version of @docendos lapply suggestion
```

Or per your newest request

```
Map(`[`, mylist, 1:3)
```